# Silent printing of an existing pdf to an network printer in c++

Tags: c++, windows, printing, ubuntu-12.04, silent

I need to print an existing pdf to a local network printer using C++ silently. Is there any known sdk for this? I tried googling for the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "silently"?

Comment: Silently as in without user intervention, no pop ups, no dialog boxes or anything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand you question but I think the [CUPS API](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-cups.html) will do under Linux. If you want to print with Linux and Windows you can use Qt.

Answer (score 0):

The [XpdfPrint](http://www.glyphandcog.com/XpdfPrint.html) library from Glyph & Cog can print a PDF to any Windows printer.